# Deadlock Using self-referential foreign key

Tags: sql, locking, foreign-keys, deadlock, indexing

Using SQL server 2005: I've got a table which has a self referencing foreign key.

A deadlock occurs when an update & an insert on this table occur simultaneously but only in the following conditions:

- the update occurs 1st
- the update is against the record which will be referenced by the foreign key of the insert statement

During the update an X lock is created on the primary key which is the clustered index of the table.  I have tried several things to try and prevent this happening such as:

- I've tried changing transaction isolation levels
- providing table hints ie WITH(nolock)
- I tried creating a non-clustered index on the primary key of the table so that this could be used instead of the clustered one.

The foreign key needs to be there so removing it is not an option.  Any suggestions on how I can either prevent the lock which stops the insert, or allow the insert to work around the lock would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you having a deadlock (one of the transactions fails with error `1205`) or a lock wait?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried separating your UPDATE and INSERT transactions by BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT. That way you stay away from deadlocks.

Something like that;

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION insert
  <INSERT SQL>
  COMMIT TRANSACTION insert
  BEGIN TRANSACTION update
     <UPDATE SQL>
  COMMIT TRANSACTION update
END
```

Comment: Unfortunately these queries happen in different stored procedures which are executed in separate threads, so it isn't possible for me to synchronously commit one after the other.

Comment: There is a common RDBMS concept called two phase commit (2PC). You can utilize this to achieve what you want. Bu you still need to use BEGIN/COMMIT sta5tements.

Here are some references;

SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa754091(v=bts.10).aspx Oracle: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10595/ds_txns003.htm MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html

Comment: what does two-phase commit have to do with this problem?

Comment: Quassnoi, u r right. The question has nothing to do with 2PC. I just got drift away from the topic. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

When a record is found eligible for `UPDATE`, an `X` lock is placed on it (or its page etc., depending on the locking granularity chosen by the engine).

This prevents placing the `S` lock on the resource affected which is required to retrieve its value.

Since inserting a value into the child table requires checking it against the parent table, the `INSERT` statement will have to wait until the `UPDATE` transaction commits or rolls back.

If you make the `PRIMARY KEY` non-clustered, `UPDATE` should not affect it (unless you are updating the `PRIMARY KEY` itself which you should not do in normal circumstances), so the `INSERT` will succeed.

The commands below work for me:

Transaction 1:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED, value INT NOT NULL, parentId INT REFERENCES parent)

INSERT
INTO    parent
VALUES  (1, 1, NULL)

BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE  parent
SET     value = 2
WHERE   id = 1
```

Transaction 2:

```
INSERT
INTO    parent
VALUES  (2, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Our issue is that there is one table and it is self-referential.  It is not possible for the child to be in a separate table.

Comment: @Stew52: didn't notice that at first, my fault :) However, this makes no difference. Please see the post update.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide DDL and your `UPDATE` / `INSERT` statements I can't reproduce this.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
refid int references T(id),
filler char(10)
)

INSERT INTO T (refid)
select number 
FROM master..spt_values where number between 1 and 2248
```

#### Connection 1

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE T SET filler = 'A' WHERE id=500
```

#### Connection 2

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO T (refid) VALUES (500) /*Blocked - No deadlock*/
```

Comment: 99% of users mean `lock` when talking of `deadlock`. They should have called it `lock resolution error` or whatever.

Comment: You are correct, we are seeing a wait lock when running procedures from the query windows in sql server. However we do have a deadlock in this area of code & a trace log highlighting these procedures as the cause.  Our current thinking is this is a possible cause for the deadlock.

Comment: @Stew52 - Do you have a deadlock graph? If so could you please edit the XML into your question?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this exact same problem.  As mentioned in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/e2ee0a1e-a911-43df-b130-ae6fdb9e49d9/), the solution for me was to simply add an index on the self-referencing column (not the pk).  After that, the deadlocks completely disappeared.